# How to skip or jump a parameter/key in the mongo collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's say I have a mongo collection A with data

```
[
{
name: "job",
pass: "123"
},
{
name: "Uob",
pass: "123"
},
{
name: "bob",
pass: "123"
}
]
```

And I use A.find() method to fetch all data.
I'm in a situation where I want to fetch all data from the collection A. But I need only the name field. How to get it ?

I am writing this backend in nodejs, Is there a way how can I prevent pass field getting fetched ?

Comment: see [find projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) documentation, before asking question just google it or refer reference document of specific method.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this:

```js
let response = await User.find({},{ pass: 0 });
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1o-HL57B_Fm

Comment: Actually I'm writing backend in nodejs. The above data is a sample data. I have a collection with name, email, phone, etc. and I want to prevent from password field getting displayed.```let response = await User.find({
        rolee:rolee
        },{
            userId: 1
        });```

Comment: I tried using this but it did not work, Can you help me sorting it out.

Comment: Add Schema in your question.

Comment: I updated my answer and working example. Can you check it?

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Consider also approving my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate

db.con.collection('A').aggregate([
{$project:{name:1}]).toArray()

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/